# How to use Tiled in Java

Tags: java, tiled

I am fairly new to Java and totally new to Tiled.

I want to use Tiled to try a couple of things with AI.

I found this to use Tiled in Java:
https://github.com/bjorn/tiled

I installed it, made the Jar and added the library. But I cannot find any documentation on how to use it.

Are there docs somewhere or do just use a bad library?

Comment: Check the website: http://www.mapeditor.org/ There is a link to documentation (https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki) there, and other resources also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For libtiled-java, the documentation is following the Javadoc standard and the HTML pages can be generated by building the `javadoc` target using `ant`. These docs are pretty much only suitable for reference though and not really helpful to get started. You may just want to look at the tmxviewer-java example to see the basic usage.

I have to warn you that libtiled-java is out of date and may even fail to load your map. Please feel free to report any issues you run into on the Tiled issue tracker at https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/issues